# How i can create a toolbar for a specific perspective in rcp?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am very new to rcp. In my plugin, I have three perspectives and In a perspective, I have 4-5 views, I want to create a toolbar specific to the slected perspective. I searched a lot for this but unable to find any answer, please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create an extension using org.eclipse.ui.actionSets that contains a set of actions you want to be displayed in the tool bar when a specific perspective is selected. Then there is a extension point called org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions where you can associated a action set ID (the one you created) with a persepctive ID and that action set is only shown when the perspective is active. In terms of "creating your own tool bar" that is in clear. There is always only one toolbar but based on the perspective/view selection items can be hidden or active.

Comment: Hi Duncan Krebs,
 I tried but it is not working for me. Can you please upload a demo example.

Answer (score -1):

This thread is dead and the answer posted is no more valid. so it doesn't help me. please refer the link below.

This question is correct, on which no one is responding, after last response. The Last repose which is not correct for the current eclipse development, as actionSets is a deprecated API now. Below link clearly mentions that this is deprecated.

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html

I have same related question and created another thread, which addresses more than this question too. Hope that is helpful.

[In RCP Eclipse(Neon) Development, how to enable a created perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820623/in-rcp-eclipseneon-development-how-to-enable-a-created-perspective)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks! i have added the relevant information for my comment support. Infact i have added my thread here to get the help