# In RCP Eclipse(Neon) Development, how to enable a created perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, eclipse-neon

I have created the Perceptive Stack and added 2 perspective in Application.e4xmi. Then i have created 2 perspective class in my package and connected them via class URI.

Now i am new to rcp development and I want to invoke one of the perspective.

1. First i want to enable the toolbar of perspective of eclipse(as i am
   willing to extend and use the perspective feature of eclipse). (refer image below)
   [image: Eclipse built in Perspective toolbar]
2. Then I want to see only my perspectives in in the perspective menu. and 
   (Refer image below)
   [image: Eclipse Perceptive window]
3. My perspectives show in the menu should do the same work the perceptive    clicking works in eclipse.
   (Refer image below)

[image: Eclipse Perceptive window click my own perspectives]

Finally this should be the outcome. please see the image below

[image: My application should look like this if i am able to achieve eclipse perspective feature]

Any help will be great..

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking. With an e4 application you have to code your own perspective switcher (such as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35063724/2670892))

Comment: The link you pasted is actually something i am looking for. in the link i came to know that "EPartService.switchPerspective" will do the switch thing from the code. But i have updated the question now.

Comment: As I said in e4 you have to code all this yourself. You won't see the old 3.x perspectives as they aren't in your Application.e4xmi.

Comment: i still think there should be a way.. to unleash the persepctive feature of eclipse

Comment: i still think there should be a way.. to unleash the perspective feature of eclipse.I still haven't give up yet... i got something "org.eclipse.ui.model 
 - Provides a workbench adapter for displaying workbench elements in the UI without having to know the concrete type of the element, and various label providers for workbench-specific objects like editors, views, and perspectives."

Comment: Everything in `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` is Eclipse 3.x compatibility code, you cannot use this in a pure e4 application.